# After Reboot Bookmarks in files in ubuntu 20.04 do not work

Tags: 20.04, files, bookmarks

I actually bookmarked some folder in files and works good but when I reboot my laptop then when I try to open bookmark then I get a warning

> Oops! Something went wrong .
>
> > Unable to find the respected file.Please check the spelling and try again

So Thankyou for solving my problem in advance.

Keval Shah

Comment: Where is the folder you are trying to access located? You need to give some details.

Comment: When I try to acess any volume or folder this error is shown when I reboot